# Plot outline around raster cells

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot2 I would like to plot a polygon (convex hull?) that honours the cell boundaries of a raster plot (created with `geom_raster`). I can use convex hull methods but they would pass through the x-y coordinates rather than around the cells of the raster plot (sorry my terminology is affected by my ignorance). As an example, given the following x-y coordinate data with categorical attribute `d`:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(295, 300, 305, 310, 295, 300, 305, 310),
                 y = c(310, 310, 310, 310, 315, 315, 315, 315),
                 d = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1))
```

I can use ggplot2's `geom_raster` to plot the attribute as a fill:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = d)) +
  coord_fixed()
```

To give:

[image]

But what I want is an outline hull of the categories defined by `d`. Something like this:

[image]

Can I do this with base R and ggplot2 or is there a way using the `raster` package or some other grid/raster/GIS package? I prefer to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly get those polygons using R's spatial facilities. Here's one way:

```
library(raster)

## Convert your data.frame to a raster object
r <- rasterFromXYZ(df)

## Extract polygons
pp <- rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve=TRUE)

## Convert SpatialPolygons to a format usable by ggplot2
outline <- fortify(pp)

## Put it all together:
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_raster(aes(fill = d)) +
    coord_fixed() +
    geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = outline, 
              size=1.5, col="gold")
```

[image]

Comment: That works but is only part of the way there for me. Is there a way to use the polygon object as a layer in ggplot2? Perhaps another raster package conversion routine?

Comment: @AlexT Try, for example, doing `obj <- fortify(pp)` and then appending this to the `ggplot()` call in your example:  `geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = obj)`. It works, even though I'm guessing it's not exactly how a **ggplot2** user would do it...

Comment: That works nicely. I seem to have to load the maptools package for fortify to work. I can combine the entire transform in a dplyr string, which makes it nice and readable: `outline <- df %>%  rasterFromXYZ() %>% rasterToPolygons(dissolve = TRUE) %>% fortify(region = "d")`

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer with the `fortify` step.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `fortify()` from {ggplot2} is no longer recommended by the package authors. The suggested replacement, `tidy()` from the {broom} package is also no longer recommend by *those* package authors!

Fortunately, we can recreate Josh O'Brien's answer using the {sf} package. We still rely on some functions from the {raster} package, but these might be replaceable with the {stars} package once a presumed bug is fixed (see https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1389). Using {stars} might be advantageous if your raster is very large, because converting the raster (or dataframe) to contiguous polygons can be very slow (see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/313550/114075).

Here's the code (borrowing from Josh O'Brien's setup):

```
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

df <- data.frame(x = c(295, 300, 305, 310, 295, 300, 305, 310),
                 y = c(310, 310, 310, 310, 315, 315, 315, 315),
                 d = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1))

## Convert your data.frame to a raster object
r <- raster::rasterFromXYZ(df)

## Extract polygons
pp <- raster::rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve = TRUE)

## Convert SpatialPolygons to a format usable by ggplot2
outline <- sf::st_as_sf(pp)

## Put it all together:
## The polygon "outline" is filled by default so will cover up the
## raster values. Use fill = NA for the geom_sf() to just use the
## gold border color. 
ggplot(df) +
  geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = d)) +
  geom_sf(data = outline, size = 1.5, col = "gold", fill = NA)
```

Alternatively, cast the `sf` object to be a `LINESTRING`, then there is no need to use the `fill = NA` argument in the call to `geom_sf()`:

```
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

df <- data.frame(x = c(295, 300, 305, 310, 295, 300, 305, 310),
                 y = c(310, 310, 310, 310, 315, 315, 315, 315),
                 d = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1))

## Convert your data.frame to a raster object
r <- raster::rasterFromXYZ(df)

## Extract polygons
pp <- raster::rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve = TRUE)

## Or you can cast to a linestring instead of using a polygon
## and then having to use the fill = NA argument in the 
## geom_sf() call
outline <- sf::st_as_sf(pp) %>% st_cast("LINESTRING")

ggplot(df) +
  geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = d)) +
  geom_sf(data = outline, size = 1.5, col = "gold")
```

[image]